# Are edits okay while still in beta?

Tags: discussion

I'm kind of a beginner at Joomla! and can therefore not contribute much in terms of the currently accepted questions and answers. But I noticed that some spelling and grammar issues exist in some questions and answers which I can contribute to.

Are edits acceptable while we (the StackExchange site) are still in beta stage?

Comment: I definitely think so, it was mentioned also in the account activation email. And it's not requested to be a _pro_!

Comment: @MattAllegro Thanks, I just saw that it is indeed mentioned in the invitation - missed that :)

Comment: Q: How can I help the site succeed?
A: During the private beta, ask questions, answer questions, tag questions, edit questions, and vote. !!

Comment: As a professional who works with Joomla a lot, I've had my one question on here edited to have a better title. If you can offer a suggestion to make the question or answer better, edit away! Just don't think that your only contribution will be spelling and grammar. The best way to learn is to try and teach!

Comment: @DavidFritsch valid point. I'll definitely be asking my own questions once we are in public beta - the invitation mentions asking _expert_ questions for now to attract the experts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

definitely

Ok that answer would be a bit short ;-).

I think its important to have correct spelling and good looking answers and questions ^^, we have many not native English speaker, like me, that would really appreciated to be corrected in spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 5):

Not only spelling can be improved, but some questions tend to have:

- an unclear title / question
- too much text describing the question / issue
- wrong tags
- flag questions you think need a moderator attention

So yes, go ahead and edit.